# How can I create an Action<T> in F#?

Tags: linq, f#, quotations

I am using the Moq framework for unit testing and would like to be able to pass in Action for logging void methods.

```
let log = new Mock<ILog>()
let quot = <@ fun (mock:ILog) -> mock.Info(It.IsAny<string>) @>  
let expr = (quot.ToLinqExpression() :?> Expression<Action<ILog>>)
log.Verify(expr)
```

This code fails with the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Action`1[log4net.ILog]]'.

I can print the type out using

```
printfn "%s" (quot.Type.ToString())
```

which outputs

> Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[log4net.ILog,Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit]

So, how can I create an Action?

Comment: Moq in F# -> probably a bad idea.

Comment: Yeps, in F#, we Foq instead - see http://trelford.com/blog/post/Foq.aspx and http://trelford.com/blog/post/FoqItEasy.aspx (Very easy transition from Moq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
let quot = <@ new Action<_>(fun (mock:ILog) -> mock.Info(It.IsAny<string>)) @>
```

Comment: This created the action correctly but still didn't work out for Moq.

Answer (score 14):

LINQ Expressions are fully supported in F# 3, so you can now pass an Action to Moq as a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233201.aspx):

```
let mock = Mock<ILog>()
mock.Verify(fun (log:ILog) -> log.Info(It.IsAny<string>()))
```